# What is inside code for array.length() in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

What is stored in 10th location of array
say

```
int[] array=new int[10];
```

Say we have values stored from `array[0]` to `array[9]`, if I were to print elements without using

```
array.length()
```

or `for (int a: array)`

How do I proceed?

My basic question is how will JVM determine end of array, is it when a null is encountered parsing array or when a garbage value is encountered? what is inbuilt code of `array.length()` function?

Comment: length() isn't a method, it's a final field - so you don't need the `()` after it.

Comment: You *still* can use a *sentinel value* in Java: it's *Undefined Behavior* to read outside of an array/"object" in C; in Java it's a guaranteed Exception. However, in the well-behaving cases it's identical. However, since a Java array *knows* it's size (unlike a pointer-to-array-thing in C) then no sentinel is required, even if it could be used. Imagine this in C: `struct myarray_t { int length; void* data; }`

Answer (score 5):

> What is stored in 10th location of array say
>   ...
>   my basic question is how will JVM determine end of array, is it when a null is encountered parsing array or when a garbage value is encountered? what is inbuilt code of array.length() function?

***Welcome C/C++ programmer :-)***

Java uses a different paradigm than C/C++ for arrays.  C/C++ uses the terminator/sentinel a.k.a. "garbage") value like NULL to indicate the end of the array.  In Java, arrays are more like objects with a special "instance variable"-like variable `length` that indicates how many slots there are in the array. This special "instance variable" is set at the array's creation and is read-only.  Its accessible by saying array`.length`.

Java expects the code to know when to stop at the end of the array by making sure they don't specify an index greater than `length - 1`.  However, the JVM checks every access to the array for security reasons just in case.  If the JVM finds an array index that is less than `0` or greater than `length - 1`, then the JVM throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

> What is stored in 10th location of array

Since we can always check the length, there is no need for a marker at the end of the array in Java.  There isn't anything special after the last item in the array (it likely will be some other variable's memory).

> if I were to print elements without using `array.length()`

```
for(int a: array) {
    // code of loop body here
}
```

This code is magically transformed by the compiler to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int a = array[i];
    // code of loop body here
}
```

However, the `i` index variable isn't accessible to the user's code. This code still uses array.length implicitly.

Comment: +1 For showing the magic transformation -- have a reference to it in the JLS or similar?

Comment: Its termed "enhanced for loop".  See **II. Semantics** here http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html and see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2 ("Then the meaning of the enhanced for statement is given ...").

Comment: in fact, the `.length` variable could be called a **constant**.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are objects with a length field. While looping, Java loads the length field and compares the iterator against it.

See [10.7 Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html#64347) in the JLS

Comment: Hello Roflcoptr, in above example, how will you print elements without using array.length() or the for loop I mentioned. I am confused , can you elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: It's not explicitly the developer that uses the length field, but the compiler.

Comment: In that case, can you show how to print elements without using the methods we have discussed above? The motivation behind this question is: C stores a null value that Developer can mention in a for loop to stop going beyond that point and print all elements before null, how will you do this in Java?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do that, but if you absolutely want to do something like that you should check for a 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'

Comment: Have a link to a reference which defines `for(:)`? E.g. how does it work in light of an `array` vs. a `Collection`? I would imagine special-casing in the former.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, the JVM can track the length of an array however it sees fit.  There's actually a bytecode instruction called `arraylength` that the Java compiler emits whenever you try to get the length of an array, indicating that it's up to the JVM to determine the best way to track the length of an array.

Most implementations probably store arrays as a block of memory whose first entry is the length of the array and whose remaining elements are the actual array values.  This allows the implementation to query the length of the array, along with any value in the array, in O(1).  If the implementation wanted to, though, it could store the elements followed by a sentinel value (as you've suggested), but I don't believe that any implementations do this because the cost of looking up the length would be linear in the size of the array.

As for how the foreach loop works, the compiler translates that code into something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    T arrayElem = arr[i];
    /* ... do work here ... */
}
```

And finally, with regards as to what the 10th element of a 10-element array is, there's no guarantee that there's even an object at that location.  The JVM could easily allocate space for the array in a way where there is no tenth element.  Since you can't ever actually get this value in Java (it would throw an exception if you tried), there's no requirement that the JVM even have something meaningful there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello templatetypedef, thank you , how will you print elements without using array.length or for loop I mentioned in above example.

Comment: @ranjanarr- Without some knowledge of the size of the array you won't be able to print out all the elements.  You have a few options.  You could store the size in some other variable, and then use that as the upper bound for your iteration.  If you know what values are permissible in the array, you could store some value at the end of the array that is known not to be in the array, then iterate up to that.  But my main question is why you're trying to do this - the `length` field is the most correct way to do this.

Comment: The motivation behind this question is: C stores a null value that Developer can mention in a for loop to stop going beyond that point and print all elements before null, how will you do this in Java? without using array.length, I agree array.length is the conventional method, I was looking for any other option if available. Thanks

Comment: @ranjanarr- Your above statement about C arrays is only partially true.  C-style *strings* do store a NUL byte at the end of strings to mark the end, but more general C-style arrays do not do this.  In fact, if you try to do this for any other type of C array, you'll probably crash the program by reading way off the end of the array.  Moreover, this design pattern is extremely hard to use correctly; just look at all the security holes in `gets`, `strcpy`, etc.  I don't think it's a good idea to adopt this in Java, where you already know how big an array is.

Comment: @ranjanarr: This isn't C. Why are you trying to force C symantics onto java. The reason that you do this in C is because there are no objects in C, and null terminating an array is the only way to do this.

Comment: @templatetypedef I would imagine that the asymptotic performance requirements of `arrays` are documented somewhere in the JLS.

Comment: @Falmarri There are actually "objects" in C (think: that data which it is permissible to access) A buffer-overflow in C occurs when the *desired* object is not being accessed ;-) Also there is nothing inherent about requiring a sentinel value in C vs. passing in a length separately or using a discreet structure to represent this. Just some pedantic comments.

Answer (score 1):

Define what a "garbage value" is.  (Hint: since everything is binary, there is no such thing unless you use a sentinel value, and that's just bad practice).

The length of the array is stored inside the `Array` instance as a member variable.  It's nothing complex.

Comment: Hello Donnie, what is stored in 11th cell, i.e array[10] location in my example? we know JVM throws error if we print outofbound. But I am confused. Thank you.

Comment: @ranjanarr in C/C++ that might not be an exception: but it's still *undefined behavior* (and the program is free to crash or eat all the spinach in your fridge). Java just makes the behavior well-defined. I added a comment to the main post.

Comment: It's slightly more complex because arrays have special magic built into the byte-code and types but... yeah. That about sums it up +1.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here I go :-)

### Ways to deal with "arrays" in C

In C there are numerous ways to deal with array. For the remainder I will talk about `string*` (and use the variable `strings` which has a type of `string*`). This is because `t[]` "effectively decomposes" into `t*` and `char*` is the type of a "C string". Thus `string*` represents a pointer to "C string". This glosses over a number of pedantic issues in C w.r.t. "arrays" and "pointers". (Remember: just because a pointer can be accessed as `p[i]` doesn't make the *type* an array in C parlance.)

Now, `strings` (of type `string*`) has no way to know it's size -- it only represents a *pointer* to some string, or NULL perhaps. Now, let's look at some of the ways we can "know" the size:

**Use a sentinel value.** In this I am assuming the use NULL as the sentinel value (or it might be -1 for an "array" of integers, etc.). Remember that C has no such requirement that arrays have a sentinel value so this approach, like the following two, *is just convention*.

```
string* p;
for (p = strings; p != NULL; p++) {
   doStuff(*p);
}
```

**Track the array size externally.**

```
void display(int count, string* strings) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    doStuff(strings[i]);
  }
}
```

**Bundle the "array" and the length together.**

```
struct mystrarray_t {
  int size;
  string* strings;
}

void display(struct mystrarray_t arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.size i++) {
    doStuff(arr.strings[i]);
  }
}
```

### Java uses this last approach.

Every *array object* in Java has a fixed sized which can be accessed as `arr.length`. There is special byte-code magic to make this work (arrays are very magical in Java), but at the *language level* this is exposed as just a read-only integer field that *never changes* (remember, each array object has a fixed size). Compilers and the JVM/JIT can take advantage of this fact to optimize the loop.

Unlike C, Java *guarantees* that trying to access an index out of bounds *will* result in an Exception (for performance reasons, even if it were not exposed, this would require the JVM kept track of the length of each array). In C this is just *undefined behavior*. For instance, if the sentinel value wasn't *within the object* (read "the desired accessibly memory") then example #1 would have lead to a buffer-overflow.

However, **there is nothing to prevent one from using sentinel values in Java**. Unlike the C form with a sentinel value, this is also safe from IndexOutOfBoundExceptions (IOOB) because the length-guard is the ultimate limit. The sentinel is just a break-early.

```
// So we can add up to 2 extra names later
String names[] = { "Fred", "Barney", null, null };
// This uses a sentinel *and* is free of an over-run or IOB Exception
for (String n : names) {
  if (n == null) {
    break;
  }
  doStuff(n);
}
```

Or possibly allowing an IOOB Exception because we do something silly like ignore the fact that *arrays know their length*: (See comments wrt "performance").

```
// -- THERE IS NO EFFECTIVE PERFORMANCE GAIN --
// Can ONLY add 1 more name since sentinel now required to
// cleanly detect termination condition.
// Unlike C the behavior is still well-defined, just ill-behaving.
String names[] = { "Fred", "Barney", null, null };
for (int i = 0;; i++) {
  String n = strings[i];
  if (n == null) {
    break;
  }
  doStuff(n);
}
```

On the other hand, **I would discourage the use of such primitive code** -- better to just use a suitable data-type such as a List in *almost* all cases.

Happy coding.

Comment: `--> -- THERE IS NO EFFECTIVE PERFORMANCE GAIN --` there is performance degrade, VM checks only once after the end of the loop for boundaries; for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) is checked only a single time. Regarding the despise part arrays have very good optimizations and allow real atomic access (unlike the collections)

Comment: @bestsss Thanks for the information on the bounds checking. You are definitely correct about the latter -- although, in my work, I have yet to run into a case where it matters. (I suspect the people writing 3d game engines in Java have a different story.)

Comment: the funny part is that 3D actually requires DirectBuffers to communicate to the native part and the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment on another, the OP writes:

> I agree array.length is the conventional method, I was looking for any other option if available.

There is no other reasonable implementation option open to the JVM implementer ... on any mainstream hardware architecture.

In particular, the sentinel approach ONLY detects the case where an application *fetches* an array element *one* index beyond the end.

- If it fetches 2 or more indexes beyond, then it misses the sentinel and proceeds to access memory whose contents are unknown.
- If it stores, then the sentinel is not consulted.
- If it needs to directly access the array size as part of the application algorithm, searching for a sentinel is a very inefficient way of doing it.  (Not to mention unreliable; e.g. if `null` is a valid array element.)
- Sentinels don't work for (most) primitive arrays because there is no value that can be used as a sentinel.  (The idea of a primitive array holding a `null` is nonsensical from the JLS perspective, since `null` is not type compatible with any Java primitive type.)
- The garbage collector needs an array length in all cases.

In short, the length has to be stored in the array to deal with the other cases.  Storing a sentinel as well means you are wasting space storing redundant information, and CPU cycles creating the sentinel and copying it (in the GC).

Answer (score 0):

> how will you print elements without using array.length or foreach loop

You could of course loop through the array without bounds checking and then catch (and swallow) the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the end:

```
try {
  int i = 0;
  while (true) {
    System.out.println(arr[i++]);
  }
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  // so we are past the last array element...
}
```

This technically works, but it is bad practice. You should not use exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of how you'd print all the elements in the array without using either a for each loop or the `length` field, well in all honesty you just wouldn't. You could potentially just have a for loop like the following:

```
try {
    for(int i=0 ; ; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {}
```

But that's an awful way to do things!

Comment: The motivation behind this question is: C stores a null value that Developer can mention in a for loop to stop going beyond that point and print all elements before null, was wondering if there is a null reference in order to stop printing elements when it is encountered.

Comment: That's there in C to let you know when you've reached the end of an array because C will quite happily let you read / write beyond the bounds of the array if you tell it to causing chaos! In Java it's not like that, you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException if you try which is more inkeeping to how Java behaves. Regardless, exceptions shouldn't be used as normal flow control for a number of reasons, so it's definitely better to avoid this method in practice.

Comment: @ranjanarr Consider that many arrays in C *do not* have a sentinel. It's all convention in C.

Answer (score 0):

**All** array access outside the interval [0, 9] gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not only position 10. So, conceptually you could say that your whole memory (reaching with indexes from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) is filled with *sentinel values*, apart from the space of the array itself, and when reading or writing to a position filled with a sentinel, you get your exception. (And each array has its own *whole memory* to spend).
Of course, in reality no one has a whole memory for each array to spend, so the VM implements the array accesses a bit smarter. You can imagine something like this:

```
class Array<X> {

   private final int length;
   private final Class<X> componentType;

   /**
    * invoked on   new X[len] .
    */
   public Array<X>(int len, Class<X> type) {
      if(len < 0) {
          throw new NegativeArraySizeException("too small: " + len);
      }
      this.componentType = type;
      this.len = len;
      // TODO: allocate the memory

      // initialize elements:
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          setElement(i, null);
      }
   }


   /**
    *  invoked on   a.length
    */
   public int length() {
       return length;
   }


   /**
    * invoked on   a[i]
    */
   public X getElement(int index) {
      if(index < 0 || length <= index)
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("out of bounds: " + index);
      // TODO: do the real memory access
      return ...;
   }

   /**
    * invoked on   a[i] = x
    */
   public X setElement(int index, X value) {
      if(index < 0 || length <= index) {
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("out of bounds: " + index);
      }
      if(!componentType.isInstance(value)) {
         throw new ArrayStoreException("value " + value + " is of type " +
                                       value.getClass().getName() + ", but should be of type "
                                       + componentType.getName() + "!");
      }
      // TODO: do the real memory access
      return value;
   }

}
```

Of course, for primitive values the component type check is a bit simpler, since already the compiler (and then the VM bytecode verifier) checks that there are the right types, sometimes doing a type conversion, too. (And the initialization would be with the default value of the type, not null.)