# How does Java know the length of strings?

Tags: java, c, string, null-terminated

I was searching if Java strings are null-terminated like in C and came across the first answer for this:[Does java define string as null terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18414873/10701114)

Basically the link mentions that the length method tracks the length.

My question is how does it do so if it doesn't have any "end-point" like a null-terminator to tell the length method that the string has ended.$\implies$ I guess my essence of question boils down to how does getting the length of string work in memory?

Comment: My question is asking about the answer in the duplicate question

Comment: The answer says "A String object has a private length field", which is the 'count' field in the image in the second answer. i.e. it stores the length as a number when the string is created, it doesn't compute it from an end point. To get the length it just reads the stored 'count' and returns that.

Comment: @Rup For some reason, I thought that was impossible to do. Thanks for the clear up.

Comment: _Technically_, the answer to this question is not specified by the JLS. It's up to individual implementations to decide how to track the information.

Comment: @Rup+ that answer was way out of date; since 2012 there is no separate `count` or `offset` and the length of the _array_ `value` is used as the String length.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So your saying, it still stores the length the moment string is created but instead in a variable called `count` / `offset` its now in `value`?

Comment: @Leon Since Java 9 (I think) the `String` class stores the information in a `byte[]`, at least in implementations based on OpenJDK. The length of the `String` is determined from the length of that array. So what you're essentially asking is how does Java know the length of an array. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910221/6395627) may help. And here's the JLS section on arrays: [§10 Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-10.html).